# LinkedList iterator remove

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I have a question on linkedlist iterator

If I'm using next , previous and remove methods

for example :

```
name.add("Alvin")
name.add("Keven") 
name.add("Jack") 

ListIterator<String> iterator = name.listIteraot();  //|AKJ

iterator.next(); // A|KJ
iterator.next(); // AK|J

iterator.add("Nina") // AKN|J 

iterator.next(); // AKNJ| 

iterator.remove(); // AKN|
```

In the next and then remove method we remove the element before the iterator pointer as the example shows

PUT

I'm confused with the previous and then remove for example

```
myLList.add("Mary"); 
myLList.add("John"); 
myLList.add("Sue"); 

ListIterator<String> iterator = myLList.iterator 

itorator.next();
itorator.next();
itorator.add("Robert");
itorator.pervios();
itorator.pervios();
itorator.remove();

System.out.println(myLList);
```

the answer for that will be 
`[Mary , Robert , Sue ]`

how do we remove for the previous! Do we remove the element on the right?

Because I thought that the removal will be always going backward not forward

Comment: Your question is not clear, who do you want to remove ?

Comment: my question is how do we remove after using previous , do we remove the element after the iterator pointer or before ,, as you see on the second example I put about previous the answer was [Mery , Robert , Sue] but my answer for that was that we remove "Mery" after we go previous .. now which one is correct and why ? Do we remove the element before the pointer or after the pointer

Comment: Read the javadoc: it says: *Note that the remove() and set(Object) methods are not defined in terms of the cursor position; they are defined to operate on the last element returned by a call to next() or previous().* And when you post code, post code that compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my question is how do we remove after using previous , do we remove
>   the element after the iterator pointer or before?

From the documentation of [`ListIterator#remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove--) :

> Removes from the list the last element that was returned by next() or
>   previous() (optional operation). This call can only be made once per
>   call to next or previous. It can be made only if add(E) has not been
>   called after the last call to next or previous.

In other words, you don't remove after or before the pointer. The documentation specify that the `remove` method is regardless of the pointer's position and will remove the object returned by the last call to next/previous.

However, there still exist a pointer in the `ListIterator` which lies between element as described at the top of the `ListIterator` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Comment: So you mean that we remove the element that we skip to go previous ??? and the element that we skip to go next ?? it does not matter the direction of the removal !

Comment: you didn't get my point here ,, they teach us that if we are going next between elements we put a vertical line between the element and move it with each next and then when we have remove method we remove the element that is before this line ..

Comment: they teach us that also with previous method we put that line and go previous that why I was confused how did they remove John which was after the line and leave Marey which was before the line :S

Comment: yes I understand what you told me but I'm telling you what they teach me and got me confused

Comment: @MayyasahAl-Bahrani What they taught you is right. See the explanation at the top of the documentation for how the cursor is handled : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html.

Comment: @MayyasahAl-Bahrani I edited my post, maybe it is more clear for you now ?